# Return all values from objects using OPENJSON()

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my problem:
My JSON may vary based on API response and there is no guarantee that "shortTitle", for example, can be present in my JSON next time when there is a post request. I have to figure how to "loop" (if that's the correct term) through JSON to get all fieldID and contents without losing any data.

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE
// hardcoded json to simulate a post request
@json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "itemTypeID": 13,
    "authorRights": {
        "fieldID": 15,
        "content": "abcd"
    },
    "language": {
        "fieldID": 7,
        "content": "abcd"
    },
    "url": {
        "fieldID": 13,
        "content": "abcd"
    },
    "shortTitle": {
        "fieldID": 8,
        "content": "abcd"
    },
    "data": {
        "fieldID": 6,
        "content": "2022-03-02"
    },
    "summary": {
        "fieldID": 2,
        "content": "abcd"
    },
    "subject": {
        "fieldID": 60,
        "content": "abcd"
    }
}';

BEGIN

SELECT* FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(
fieldID bigint '$.data.fieldID',
content nvarchar(255) '$.data.content'
)

END;
```

This query returns fieldID and content only for "data" ([results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTKaG.png)). How can I return fieldID and content for all objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the structure of the input JSON correctly, you need to parse only nested JSON objects. So, using `OPENJSON()` with default schema and an additional `APPLY` operator is a possible solution to your problem. As is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value), the `OPENJSON()` function with default schema returns a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`, and the `type` column holds an int value that contains the type of the returned value.

```
SELECT j1.[key], j2.fieldID
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j1.[value]) WITH (fieldID bigint '$.fieldID') j2
WHERE j1.[type] = 5
```

Result:

```
key          fieldID
---------------------
authorRights 15
language     7
url          13
shortTitle   8
data         6
summary      2
subject      60
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you must explicitly enumerate all your desired columns:

```sql
SELECT* FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(
  authorRights_fieldID bigint '$.authorRights.fieldID',
  authorRights_content nvarchar(255) '$.authorRights.content',
  data_fieldID bigint '$.data.fieldID',
  data_content nvarchar(255) '$.data.content',
  -- ...
  subject_fieldID bigint '$.subject.fieldID',
  subject_content nvarchar(255) '$.subject.content',
)
```

instead of `...` fill other elements.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The problem is that i do not know the exact output from my API and i can not guarantee that my output will have the same content as i enumerate in WITH( )..